# JUnit : org.junit.experimental.Theories

Tags: java, junit4

I have implemented JUnit in my project. I found couple of good features using org.junit.experimental.theories.Theories.

One of the advantage is I could very well separate the data and test case.

JUnit version 4.12

Now the question is these classes are part of 'experimental' package. Does it mean in future releases this feature may not be available?
[This question may not be the right kind of question for SO, however it is a decision point for the solution]

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

For me it's a good question. As the FAQ and the Wiki of JUnit do not explicitely mention the `experimental` package. For `Theories` they are part at least since five years (maybe longer). So I would not expect that this feature would disappear. What might happen is that the API for those package changes.

**edit** At least in the [JUnit 5 user guide](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#api-annotations) there is a similar annotation mentioned ([@API(Experimental)](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/master/junit-commons/src/main/java/org/junit/gen5/commons/meta/API.java#L55)).

> **Experimental**
>   Intended for new, experimental features where we are looking for feedback.
>   Use this element with caution; it might be promoted to Maintained or Stable in the future, but might also be removed without prior notice, even in a patch.

Comment: Thank you for the details. Can you please mention the annotation you referred here "At least in the JUnit 5 user guide there is a similar annotation mentioned"

Comment: @Rakesh I added a direct link to the annotation. The annotation is also linked at the mentioned place in the user guide.